# How to update an Access DB from the web?

Tags: database, ms-access, forms

I'm looking for a way to create an online form that will update an Access database that has just a few tables. Does anyone know of a simple solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET should be able to do it [just fine](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_dbconnection.asp).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what web technology you use.

With Classic ASP, you can connect to the database the JET DB engine COM object that comes with any windows machine.

With ASP.NET, you can connect using OLEDB data connectors.